# Symfony 5.2 Validate json_login Request

Tags: symfony, jwt, symfony-validator

I am developing a RESTFUL API in Symfony 5.2 that allows users to authenticate with username and password in order to access it.

My firewall config for this looks like:

```
        login:
            pattern: '^/v1/login'
            methods: [POST]
            anonymous: true
            stateless: true
            provider: user_provider
            user_checker: App\Security\UserChecker
            json_login:
                check_path: '/v1/login'
                success_handler: App\Security\Handler\AuthenticationSuccessHandler
                failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
```

I have created a validator and a matching route so that I can ensure users submit valid data, like not submitting empty passwords:

```
v1_login:
    path: /v1/login
    methods: POST
    controller: App\Http\Token\Action\LoginAction
    defaults:
        _format: json
```

All my other routes are setup the same way with validators, but this one is not being called.  I think it's Symfony is ignoring this and using the user_provider, user_checker and success handler to manage it all.  But it means I can't validate the request first.

Is there something else I need to do?

Comment: Have you excluded the route in `acces_control` block ?

Comment: Your suspicions are correct.  Symfony intercepts POST /login and deals with all the authentication stuff.  Instead of using the built-in json_login authenticator, I would suggest creating a custom authenticator which pretty much gives you full control over the entire authentication process.  Symfony 5.2 actually has a [new experimental authentication approach](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-5-1-updated-security-system) which might be worth trying. Or follow the docs on creating a custom guard authenticator.